# How to get a value from a key value pair which is of type String?

Tags: java, android

I have a String as `"{"result" : "27"}"` how do I retrieve the value of 27 from the above string in java ? 
Your help would be appreciated thankyou !

Comment: Is it a hash map or JSon object or a simple String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
String string_type = "{\"result\" : \"27\"}";
JSONObject string_value = new JSONObject(string_type);
String result = string_value.getString("result");
Syatem.out.println("result :"+result);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
JSONObject string_value = new JSONObject("{"result" : "27"}");
Syatem.out.println("result :"+string_value.getString("result"));
```

Comment: This isn't valid Java.  You can't use double quotes within a string without escaping them.